# how to map xxx into an anonymous class (which only needs 2 properties) list object without creating new class?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this api controller code which get a list of files and map it into an object and then into a list. This code works.

```
 string[] filesPath = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf");

            var myDtos = new List<myDto>();

            foreach (var item in filesPath)
            {
                FileInfo fl = new FileInfo(item);

                var myDto = new myDto
                {
                    Title = fl.Name,
                    Type = "Report"
                };

                myDtos.Add(myDto);
            }

        return Ok(myDtos);
```

My question is how to map `myDtos` into an anonymous class (which only needs 2 properties) list object without creating new class? The reason to do so is `myDto` class has a 10 properties but when this method returns, it only need to return 2 properties.

Comment: Have you considered using an interface or an inherited base class?

Comment: No, I don't want to create a new class. It's okay. I found the solution by using LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be alright for your purposes? And, through deferred execution, it should also only iterate once over the file list instead of twice (since the Ok method suggests you're running it on a server and the server will have to serialize the returned data).

```
var files = Directory
    .GetFiles(path, "*.pdf")
    .Select(x =>
    {
        var info = new FileInfo(x);
        var dto = new myDto { Title = info.Name, Type = "Report" };
        return new { dto.Title, dto.Type };
    });
return Ok(files);
```